# Kivy don't get the button.text value correctly

Tags: python, loops, button, kivy

I have a problem, I have this code:

```
for j in range(1,21):
                if "Canales" in item.title:
                    self.btn = Button(text="Channel "+str(j), size=(590, 42),size_hint=(None, None), on_press=self.aces)
                    layout.add_widget(self.btn)

...

def aces(self, valor):
        print self.btn.text
```

When I print self.btn.text I don't get the text of button, I get always the last value of j, "channel 20"... Is a Bug? Is only my incapacity?...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'self.btn' is always the last created button, because you assign it in the loop, the part of the change that fixes it is the new (correct) definition of 'aces', not the bind part.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if is the most elegant solution, but i have solved with fbind

```
self.btn = Button(text="Arenavision "+str(j), size=(590, 42),size_hint=(None, None))
self.btn.fbind('on_press', self.aces, str(j))
...
def aces(self, value,arg):
        print value
```